# Pyinstaller executable doesn't run processes when hidden

Tags: python, windows, macos, pyinstaller

I'm trying to run a single-file python executable packaged with PyInstaller. The script contains system commands that need to be executed. However, when I attempt to run them (on windows) they do not execute. The thing is, they only fail to execute when the PyInstaller option `no-console` is used, which hides the console and runs it in the background.

I am using the following options: `--noconsole` and `-F`.

I have not only tried the `subprocess.open` function, but also `os.popen()`, both of which do not work.

Also, I need console output, so `os.system()` will not be an option... please answer with this in mind. Although, this function did actually execute the commands, so I think getting output is the issue. I am assuming that I have to change the standard output or something, or maybe if a command is executed without a console, the output is lost or never generated in the first place. Sorry if I sound inexperienced.

I do not have any antivirus software running on my computer, and no Windows Defender, etc. messages are appearing. I understand that this is a precarious combination - running system commands whilst hidden - I only wish to make a non-malicious program that kills another program every minute. Sorry if there is anything left unclarified... just ask if anything is unclear. Thanks :)

EDIT

Here's some code to help

```py
command = data['command']
command_split = command.split(" ")

p = subprocess.Popen(command_split, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
result = out.decode() if out else err.decode()


io.emit("client:console_output", {
    'output':result,
    'adminID':data['adminID']
})
```

EDIT 2

Understand that this function is working when the console is not hidden; therefore, it is nothing to do with the logic or code, it is solely because it is being hidden. Here is the output anyway.

```
x = "taskkill /im chrome.exe /f"
print(x.split(" "))
-> ['taskkill', '/im', 'chrome.exe', '/f']
```

Comment: If you disable console how you want to get the console output? redirect to a file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need the output as a string (if it's not encoded that's fine). For example I need the output for, say, tasklist, as one string. As I said above, I got this to work when the console is enabled, I just need to work out how to get it to work when it's hidden.

Comment: What is the `command_split` can you put a print and show an example?

Comment: Edited. Keep in mind it works when the console is not hidden, so the logic is fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE) to redirect the process output to a variable. You also need to handle subprocess `stdin` and close it manually.
Then you can simply disable console with `-w` or `--noconsole` flag.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ipconfig"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
p.stdin.close()
result = out.decode() if out else err.decode()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the command is still not running. I have edited my question to show the code

Comment: @JordanZdimirovic I almost forgot handler for `stdin`. Now it should work.

Comment: Thank You!! It works, you have no idea how much this has been hurting my brain.

Comment: This same solution (including shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE) also works when using `subprocess.run` for anyone else strolling by. Also an issue where the console window would constantly spawn and interrupt the UI when called from a Qthread.